# Office 2013 crashes on printing

Tags: windows-8, printing, microsoft-office-2013

I have installed Office 2013(64 Bit) onto my Windows 8 Professional 64 Bit machine. HOwever when i try to print to any of the printers configured on the network, all Office applications crash!

Looking at the event viewer I get the following stack trace

> Faulting application name: OUTLOOK.EXE, version: 15.0.4420.1017, time stamp: 0x506742d6 Faulting module name: gchp2600.dll, version:
>   2011.217.1.32924, time stamp: 0x4d5d02e4 Exception code: 0xc0000005 Fault offset: 0x000000000008ead5 Faulting process id: 0x22dc Faulting
>   application start time: 0x01ce0eb952f42cb9 Faulting application path:
>   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\OUTLOOK.EXE Faulting module
>   path: C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\x64\3\gchp2600.dll Report Id:
>   a6bc22d8-7aac-11e2-be79-08edb948381a Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:

I can print to from other applications and to print anything from office I first have to save it to XPS and then print from Reader!

Has anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

`gchp2600.dll` seems to a library for ur printers drivers.

Have u tried re-install/update the printers driver?

Or u might wanna try talk to their [online support](https://h50203.www5.hp.com/wclweb/wclentry.aspx?lc=en-US&cc=US)